# Speading manipulation on data.frame with dplyr in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a large `data.frame` structured like the following example `df`

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A",3), rep("B", 2), rep("C", 4)), 
                 x = c(paste0(letters[1:3],1) , paste0(letters[1:2],3), 
                       paste0(letters[1:4], 1)) , 
                 y = 1:9, z = 2:10 )
#   id  x y  z
# 1  A a1 1  2
# 2  A b1 2  3
# 3  A c1 3  4
# 4  B a3 4  5
# 5  B b3 5  6
# 6  C a1 6  7
# 7  C b1 7  8
# 8  C c1 8  9
# 9  C d1 9 10
```

In the real dataset there is an additional dimension (time) and there are many more numerical columns. I would like to manipulate `df` using the `dplyr` package (because it seems fast at these kind of operations) in the following way.

1. I need to subtract the `y` and `z` values for `x` equal to `b1` for `id == A` (`row = 2`), to `a3` for `id == B` (`row = 4`) and to `a1` for `id == C` (`row = 6`) from the remaining `y` and `z` values of `A`, `B` and `C` respectively.
2. delete the rows that have been subtracted.

The resulting data.frame would be

```
#   id  x y  z
# 1  A a1 -1 -1
# 2  A c1 1  1
# 3  B b3 1  1
# 4  C b1 1  1
# 5  C c1 2  2
# 6  C d1 3  3
```

In the real `data.frame` I have multiple numeric columns (which I didn't show for simplicity) so that these operations should be applied to all columns. Notice that the codes in `x` must refer to the `id` because different `id` can have the same `x` codes (for example `A` and `C`).

I found this possible solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cond = ifelse( (id == "A" & x == "b1") | ( id == "B" & x == "a3" ) | ( id == "C" & x == "a1" ) , 1, 0 ) ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_at(vars("y", "z"),funs(.-.[cond==1])) %>%
  filter(cond == 0)
```

it seems to work. Better/faster ideas?

Comment: As one suggestion, the first `mutate` step could be replaced by making a data.frame with your `id/x` pairs and then inner joining.

Comment: would that be faster? I'm after speed.. Willing to accept better answers then the one I proposed

Comment: Should be pretty quick. It will be a lot simpler and less error prone.

Comment: Could you write that in an answer please? I'm still learning `dplyr`

Comment: Are you open to a data.table solution? I can figure out a quick solution in that package

Comment: Sure! anything that is fast (I need to bootstrap this altogether with some other operation so speed is important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to a `data.table` solution, this should be fast:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
keys <- data.table(id=c("A","B","C"), x=c("b1","a3","a1"))
onv <- c("id","x")
vars <- c("y","z")
df[df[keys, on=onv], on=onv[1], (vars) := .SD[,..vars] - mget(paste0("i.", vars))][!keys, on=onv]

#   id  x  y  z
#1:  A a1 -1 -1
#2:  A c1  1  1
#3:  B b3  1  1
#4:  C b1  1  1
#5:  C c1  2  2
#6:  C d1  3  3
```